# Проблема multimedia qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

Скомпилировал свой проект в MinGW x64 - выпуск, я и до этого так делал
Но в моём проекте появилась необходимость заюзать multimedi'ю для музыки
Запускаю через exe файл - музыка не проигрывается, через qt creater - пишет:
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"

Вот код:

```
const QString mu(QApplication::applicationDirPath()+bt+mus);
//bt = blytype/
//mus = music/
   bg_pl->addMedia(QUrl(mu+bg+"Minus"+wav));
//bg = background/
//wav = .wav
   bg_pl->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::Loop);
   bgm->setPlaylist(bg_pl);
```

Ну и дальше проигрывание этого плейлиста и т.д

В чём проблема?
Если не добавлять dll файлы, а закомпилить в creat'оре и запустить оттуда же всё робит

Comment: Как собираешь проект? Если через qmake то вы не добавили директиву для медии в .pro. Через cmake соответственно вы так же скорее всего не нашли пакеты.

Comment: А нет ли у вас путаницы с системе с разными Qt? Разной разрядности библиотек? Установлен ли GStreamer? Вот народ обсуждает https://forum.qt.io/topic/74070/qmediaplayer-defaultserviceprovider-requestservice-no-service-found-for-org-qt-project-qt-mediaplayer-ubuntu/5

Comment: Можно пожалуйста по подробнее про GStreamer?
Как его вообще установить и что это? в инете не нашёл..

Answer (score 2):

Для того что бы подключить мультимедиа при сборки в qmake необходимо добавить следующие параметры:

Пример:

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += multimedia
```

Кроме того, если вы хотите запускать просто .exe файл, то вам необходимо после сборки и компиляции под релизом, воспользоваться утилитой:

```
windeployqt
```